# Visual studio 2010 doesn't make the changes when i do a build/compile a DLL file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ok so i change some code, re-build it and then, say for arguments sake i had a print statement outputting 'test2', well if i change it to 'test3' its still re-producing the old code 'test2'.

Ive deleted the debug folder and rebuilt but no good. Then randomly about 10 builds later it will catch up. Ive also closed VS2010 and then re-opened the project but that doesnt help.

What can i do as i need to see the changes asap?

ps it's definitely the correct file

EDIT: I've done clean and rebuild but it hasnt done anything
EDIT: This is a .dll file which im modifying

Comment: Are you sure that the compilation is successful? If it isn't, you may be running an old version of the compiled output.

Comment: Are you sure you are working in that dir where you using that dll? Maybe you trying to use DLL from bin/Release when fresh file is in bin/Debug?

Answer (score 1):

- try putting a breakpoint on that line and step through the code,
- make sure you're checking the right version(debug or release),
- check that the executable calling the dll, isnt hanging,
- if you're running this in IIS, do a iisreset in command line,
- check the task manager to make sure the process running your executable isnt still running

Answer (score 0):

can you do a rebuild instead / or do a clean first and build again.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the issue, but just in case - you might make sure the builds in-between actually succeeded. When you "Start Debugging" (F5), Visual Studio will allow you to run the last successful build if the current attempt fails with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set project dependencies?

Right-click on application (exe) project in project tree, then click "Dependencies" and set dependency. Exe project should depend on dll project. That will force dll library project to compile when you compile application file.

Also make sure, that your app have reference set to dll file which is fresh compiled, not a copy made once when you added reference to application project.